# Accuracy() and "Error in xx - ff[1:n] : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Tags: r, time-series

While building a basic predictive model using the dowjones data set from library(fma) I ran into "> Error in xx - ff[1:n] : non-numeric argument to binary operator".

```
library(forecast)
library(fma)

dj60 <- window(dowjones, end = 60)

dj60.rwf.drift <- rwf(dj60, h = 18, drift = TRUE)

dj60.od <- window(dowjones, start = 61)

accuracy(dj60.od, dj60.rwf.drift)
```

Returns:

> Error in xx - ff[1:n] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

The preceding chain of commands works for another data set (visnights from the fpp2 library):

```
library(forecast)
library(fpp2)

vn_Melbourne_train1 <- window(visnights[, "QLDMetro"], end = c(2014, 4))

snaive_vn_Melbourne_train1 <- snaive(vn_Melbourne_train1, h = 4)

vn_Melbourne_test1 <- window(visnights[, "QLDMetro"], start = c(2015, 1), end = c(2015, 4))

accuracy(snaive_vn_Melbourne_train1, vn_Melbourne_test1)
```

I have `str()`ed all of the objects and find them comparable.

Why does this error occur for one data set and not the other?

Comment: We would really need to see examples of the data to offer any advice on this.  Can you post subsets of the data that still illustrate the issue?  Use `dput()` on each variable, once it is reduced to a reasonable size; then it's easy for anyone to reproduce what you did.

Comment: @user2554330 apologies.  I didn't realize the data sets were not part into r.  I've updated the question to include the associated libraries.

Comment: I can reproduce your error.  If I run `debug(forecast:::testaccuracy)`, I can single-step up to the error.  When it happens, `x` is a timeseries in the example that works, but a complicated `forecast` object in the eaxmple that doesn't.  I'm not at all familiar with these functions, so I don't know if this is a bug in one of the packages you're using, or an error in the way you're using it.

Comment: No idea if this makes sense, but swapping the args makes the first one work:  `accuracy(dj60.rwf.drift, dj60.od)`

Comment: ?accuracy indicates "accuracy(object, x, test = NULL, d = NULL, D = NULL, f = NULL, ...)" Where x is a vector.  Are ts()s considered vectors?

Comment: You would have to ask the author of that help page.

Answer (score 1):

Read the help file `help(accuracy)`. The first argument is the forecast object, the second argument is the actual values in the test period.

`accuracy(dj60.rwf.drift, dj60.od)` should work